# Rest API call working fine without VPN , with VPN not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vpn, apigee

In my application I have some external API call , for that I am using RestTemplate to call the API which works fine when not on VPN,
but when I connect to VPN API call is not working its giving connection time out exception  .

Even I set proxy and tried that is also no use .
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","xxxxx");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","80");

if I add or remove proxy with out VPN  connection . its working fine .
VPN connect adding proxy or with out proxy it does not work .

problem here my code is not working in VPN connection

Comment: VPN and Proxy are 2 different things

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because of the proxy .You can check with your system admin and ask him for open ports and connect using those open ports.

Comment: if I add or remove proxy with out VPN  connection . its working fine .  with VPN connect adding proxy or with out proxy it does not work

Comment: Can you check with what ports can you communicate .When in vpn you are in a closed network,in order to communicate to outside world(internet) you need to have ports which allow you to do that.

Comment: both are same port only

Answer (score -1):

If your proxy is not reachable from the vpn, that may be the issue.